# Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /hsphere/local/home/aeldresa/tuc-management.dk/admin/system/functions.php on line 144

Tags: php, function, joomla, system, pass-by-reference

I have a problem that I need some help figuring out I have a Joomla site and after my host provider updated their php system I get the error Fatal error: `Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /hsphere/local/home/aeldresa/tuc-management.dk/admin/system/functions.php on line 144`

But when I look the problem up here anywhere on the internet people are saying that I just need to take away the & sign on line 144 but when I do that all hell brakes lose then I get a lot off errors like this one: Notice: Use of undefined /thefile

[A image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeUkF.png)

```
function xml_to_array ($data) {
   $data = eregi_replace(">"."[[:space:]]+"."<","><",$data);

   $p = xml_parser_create();
   xml_parser_set_option($p, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
   xml_parse_into_struct($p, $data, &$vals, &$index);
   xml_parser_free($p);

    $i = 0;
   $array = array();
   $array[] = array(
       'tag' => $vals[$i]['tag'], 
       'attributes' => decodearray ($vals[$i]['attributes']), 
       'value' => decodevalue($vals[$i]['value']), 
       'children' => GetChildren($vals, $i)
   );

   return $array;
}
```

I hope that there is someone can help me here :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not about joomla but only php version.  After php 5.3, the reference use changing.
Please look at this link : http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

> Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function
>   definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass
>   the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning
>   saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use &
>   in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was
>   removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

You can see the same problem if you do something like that :

```
str_replace('', '', &$yourVar);
```

If your code is a joomla code, i suggest you to update your joomla version. If not, we need more information for help you (you need change your own code)

Good luck, coment and ask again if you need

Answer (score 0):

You did fix the error when removing the & (we explained the process here: http://www.itoctopus.com/menu-item-manager-empty-in-joomla )

But, the errors that you are seeing are not really errors - they are just notices, and it's because the new version of PHP that you have installed has deprecated many functions and became stricter.

What you need to do is change the $error_reporting variable in your configuration.php file to -1 (I think right now it is set to something else), save it and then try again.

If you still see errors then you will need to fix them manually in the code (by just defining variables first, for example). Trust me, you probably only have a few errors (notices) but they are repeated many times, and that's why it looks like there are so many errors.

Hope this helps!